# Multiple patterns with multiple contexts?

Tags: design-patterns, grep

I want grep to search for two patterns, and output different lines of context for each match: e.g, when it matches "warning", output 1 line before and 1 line after - and when it matches "error", output 1 line before, and 2 lines after; so I tried this:

```
$ echo -ne "1\n2\n3\n4\nwarning\n5\n6\n7\n8\nerror\n9\n10\n11\n12\n" | grep -e "warning" -A 1 -B 1 -e "error" -B 1 -A 2
4
warning
5
6
--
8
error
9
10
```

... however, unfortunately it doesn't work - apparently, only the final `-B`/`-A` arguments are effectuated for all patterns.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve separate context for each search pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this variant using `sed`?

```
sed -n '/warning/{x;p;x;p;n;p};/error/{x;p;x;p;n;p;n;p};h'
```

Where `x` means *Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces*,
`p` means *Print the current pattern space*
`n` means *Read the next line of input into the pattern space*
`h` means *Copy pattern space to hold space*
`sed -n` means *suppress automatic printing of pattern space* (i.e. print only when `p` occurs)

Comment: Awesome, thanks @bmk for the nice explanation - don't know much the `sed` syntax, so I'll have to get used to it, I guess; but it works fine.... Cheers!

Comment: Hi again, just wanted to also leave the syntax for the `sed` equivalent of a "plain grep" - say, `grep 'compact' /proc/vmstat` - which helps me in reading this answer... and that equivalent would be: `sed -n '/compact/{p};' /proc/vmstat` (_with or without the `{};` characters_).