# Show different context on different grep keyword?

Tags: bash, search, grep

I know `-A` `-B` `-C` could be used to show context around the grep keyword.

My question is, **how to show different context on different keyword?**

For example, how do I show `-A 5` for cat, `-B 4` for dog, and `-C 1` for monkey:

```
egrep -A3 "cat|dog|monkey" <file> 
// this just show 3 after lines for each keyword.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041720/grep-multiple-patterns-with-multiple-contexts>
There is a very nice solution using sed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think there's any way to do it with a single grep call, but you could run it through grep once for each variable and concatenate the output:

```
var=$(grep -n -A 5 cat file)$'\n'$(grep -n -B 4 dog file)$'\n'$(grep -n -C 1 monkey file)
var=$(sort -un <(echo "$var"))
```

now `echo "$var"` will produce the same output as you would have gotten from your single command, plus line numbers and context indicators (the `:` prefix indicates a line that matched the pattern exactly, and the `-` prefix indicates a line being included because of the `-A` `-B` and/or `-C` options).

the reason i included the line numbers thus far is to preserve the order of the results you would have seen had you managed to do this in one statement.  if you like them, great, but if not, you can use the following line to cut them out:

```
var=$(cut -d: -f2- <(echo "$var") | cut -d- -f2-)
```

this passes it through once to cut the exact matching lines' prefixes, then again to cut the context matches' prefixes.

pretty? no.  but it works.

Comment: +1 for the solution, but the multiple cuts would fail if the matching line contained a "-" and you don't need the variable or the echo, which could introduce other failures. I think this would do it: `$ ( f="file"; grep -n -A 5 cat "$f"; grep -n -B 4 dog "$f"; grep -n -C 1 monkey "$f" ) | sort -un | sed -r 's/^[^:-]+[:-]//'`. I just introduced "f" to save from having to specify the same file name multiple times.

Comment: i thought the cut would be okay since i specified `-f2-`, which tells it to print field 2 through the end of the line.  so even if the rest contained a `-` or `:` it should still be okay.  (am i wrong in thinking that?) but otherwise i agree with your comment, and like your introduction of $f in place of repeating the filename.

Comment: the problem with `cut -d: | cut -d-` is that lines that just happen to contain one of those characters will get truncated AGAIN. For example if you had 2 lines like `7:rounded-up` and `9-it's 10:30` and you wanted to print `rounded-up` and `it's 10:30` respectively you'd actually end up printing `up` and `30`.

Comment: ahh, i understand what you're saying now, and you are right. i didn't think about the case of a line containing a `-` and a `:`.  if something only had one of them multiple times, it would still be okay, but if something has both, it does get chopped again unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid `grep` won't do that.  You'll have to use a different tool.  Perhaps write your own program.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```
awk '
   BEGIN{ ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[1] }

   function prtB(nr) { for (i=FNR-nr; i<FNR;     i++) print a[i] }
   function prtA(nr) { for (i=FNR+1;  i<=FNR+nr; i++) print a[i] }

   NR==FNR{ a[NR]; next }

   /cat/    { print; prtA(5) }
   /dog/    { prtB(4); print }
   /monkey/ { prtB(1); print; prtA(1) }

' file
```

check the math on the loops in the functions. You didn't say how you'd want to handle lines that contain monkey AND dog, for example.

EDIT: here's an untested solution that would print the maximum context around any match and let you specify the contexts on the command line and won't use as much memory as the above cheap and cheerful solution:

```
awk -v cxts="cat:0:5\ndog:4:0\nmonkey:1:1" '
   BEGIN{
      ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[1]
      numCxts = split(cxts,cxtsA,RS)
      for (i=1;i<=numCxts;i++) {
         regex = cxtsA[i]
         n = split(regex,rangeA,/:/)
         sub(/:[^:]+:[^:]+$/,"",regex)
         endA[regex]   = rangeA[n]
         startA[regex] = rangeA[n-1]
         regexA[regex]
      }
   }

   NR==FNR{
      for (regex in regexA) {
         if ($0 ~ regex) {
            start = NR - startA[regex]
            end   = NR + endA[regex]
            for (i=start; i<=end; i++) {
               prt[i]
            }
         }
      }
      next
   }

   FNR in prt

' file
```

Separate the searched for patterns in the cxts variable with whatever your RS value is, newline by default.